# Существует ли плагин для валидации пошаговой формы, удовлетворяющий таким требованиям?

Tags: jquery, валидация

Нужен вот такой плагин-комбайн:

1. валидация форм как в поэтапном режиме (`multistep form`), так и в обычном
2. возможность кастомизации селектов и инпутов `[type='radio']` и `[type="checkbox"]` (то есть встроенные аналоги `chosen` и `icheck`, к примеру)
3. желательно наличие аналога maskeinput, чтобы в поле телефон можно было вбивать только по маске

Проблема в том, что когда я начал кастомизировать многошаговую форму, которая валидируется через `jquery-steps` и `validate` - полезли ошибки. Кастомные чекбоксы и селекты (использовал `chosen` и `icheck`) не проходят надлежащую проверку, а для текстового поля с телефоном (навешан плагин `maskeinput`) пришлось писать костыль...

Вот и задумался - нет ли готового решения, включающее всё необходимое?